# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: nlp

I am trying to import en_core_web_sm in my jupyter notebook.

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'
```

Comment: pip install ...

Comment: Run this on your command prompt. `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm'